# Keeping html tags in PHP post

Tags: php, xml

I have code that sends via PHP POST a FedEx tracking link in an xml file. when it goes the tags for the link are broken down into characters like below. What are I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$tracking_url = '<a href="http://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=' . 
    $_POST['tracking'] . '" target="_blank">' . $_POST['tracking'] . '</a>';
    $_POST['skuMessage3'] = $_POST['skuMessage2']. ' ' . $tracking_url;
```

And here is what they get on the other end.

```
&lt;a href="http://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=782663509917" target="_blank"&gt;782663509917&lt;/a&gt
```

and here is what I want.

```
<a href="http://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=782663509917" target="_blank">782663509917</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you echo `$tracking_url` the characters are encoded or is there some other steps in the process? You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php but you should figure out where you (or what) is encoding them..

Comment: the $_POST['skuMessage3'] variable is insert into an array named $data that is sent to a parsing function

Comment: Sounds like that parsing function encodes the special XML characters so either use the variable before or decode where you need it linked.